# Docker - Watch logs in real time while building image

Tags: docker, npm

I'm building a Docker image from a `Dockerfile`, but I dont know if when I execute the `npm install` command, the server is installing the dependencies from `packege.json`. I want to check in real time the progress of the dependencies installation, is it possible?

CMD:
    `docker build -t angular-frontend:prod .`

OUTPUT:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.264 MB
Step 1 : FROM node:carbon
---> 99bbd77c18fe
Step 2 : WORKDIR /app
---> Running in 1d914a408725
---> fca47246ff16
Removing intermediate container 1d914a408725
Step 3 : COPY package.json /app/
---> 793227e711d4
Removing intermediate container 1f9c5341747e
Step 4 : RUN npm install
---> Running in ddee013be29c
```

What do I want: 
See whats happening inside the container. Any hints?

Comment: Docker build shows stdout / stderr of processes it's running, IIRC.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is not a Docker problem. Docker outputs the logs during build. For instance, if you do `RUN composer update` in your Dockerfile, then you get the output. For example, here's our `RUN composer update` output  during Dockerfile build on codeship:

[image: our RUN composer update]

See? The output is right there! So, what you need is to tell your `npm` to log verbosely:

```
RUN npm install --loglevel verbose
```

This should output the logs in real time and also save your log into `npm-debug.log` file.